# Jquery function is called incremently

Tags: jquery, function

I'm probably making a huge error in the way I'm doing stuff and that's probably why this error occurs; I have an empty div in an iframe. On click the div will be replaced with content. While I add the content, a div with tools need to be inserted before the inserted div as well.

Every time I insert the div, it works. But the second time, two divs are inserted, the third three and so on.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, my guess is it has something to do with the reattachment of a function. Tried using .off() in a lot of places but didn't work and delegating the click event didn't work either. I stripped it down to keep it readable.

Any tips or pointers are much appreciated!

Calling on page load:

```
if($('#page-editor').length >= 1)
{
    // If iframe is done loading
    $(pageEditor).on('load', function (e)
    {
        // Check if iframe has contents
        if($(pageEditor).contents())
        {
            // Click event for empty div
            widgetClickEvent($(pageEditor).contents().find('#content .row[data-widget="empty"][data-editable="true"]'));
        }
    });
}
```

The click event function

```
function widgetClickEvent(attach)
    {
        // Click event
        $(attach).on('click', function(e)
        {
            // Get Id
            selectedRow = '#' + $(this).attr('id');

            // On submit of form
            $('.widgets-modal form').submit(function(e)
            {
                // Add widget
            addWidget(selectedRow, data, dataWidget);
            });
        });
    }
```

And the code adding the widget

```
function addWidget(selectedRow, data, dataWidget)
{
    // Insert html in the selected div
    $(pageEditor).contents().find(selectedRow).html(data).attr('data-widget', dataWidget).attr('data-editable', 'false').before(addWidgetTools(pageEditor, 'tools-' + selectedRow.substr(1))).off();
}
```

Other functions as mentioned

```
// Add empty widget
function addEmptyWidgetHtml()
{
    var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
    $('#page-editor').contents().find('#content .row').each(function(e)
    {
        if($(this).attr('id') === id)
        {
            var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
        }
    });
    var html = '<div class="row" data-editable="true" data-widget="empty" id="' + id + '"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></div>';
    return html;
}

// Add widget tools html
function addWidgetTools(pageEditor, id)
{
    return '<div class="row widget-tools" id="' + id + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>';
}
```

So my code looks like this (after three clicks, notice the .widget-tools)

```
<div class="row" data-editable="true" data-widget="empty" id="467645"></div>
<div class="row widget-tools" id="tools-135480"></div>
<div class="row" data-editable="false" data-widget="text" id="135480"></div>
<div class="row widget-tools" id="tools-700883"></div>
<div class="row widget-tools" id="tools-700883"></div>
<div class="row" data-editable="false" data-widget="blockquote" id="700883"></div>
<div class="row widget-tools" id="tools-607461"></div>
<div class="row widget-tools" id="tools-607461"></div>
<div class="row widget-tools" id="tools-607461"></div>
<div class="row" data-editable="false" data-widget="text" id="607461"></div>
```

And how I need it to look:

```
<div class="row" data-editable="true" data-widget="empty" id="467645"></div>
<div class="row widget-tools" id="tools-135480"></div>
<div class="row" data-editable="false" data-widget="text" id="135480"></div>
<div class="row widget-tools" id="tools-700883"></div>
<div class="row" data-editable="false" data-widget="blockquote" id="700883"></div>
<div class="row widget-tools" id="tools-607461"></div>
<div class="row" data-editable="false" data-widget="text" id="607461"></div>
```

Comment: That's what you get when you bind event handlers in the context of another event handler.

Comment: `$('.widgets-modal form').submit( function(){...` is incremental. It appends the same function at every click. So if you click three times, the `.submit` function will be attached and executed three times. Try adding `.unbind()` before `.submit`, to clear all previous functions attached.

Comment: What about:
http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: @JeremyThille; that worked! Thanks!
@Vohuman; If you have suggestions or pointers of how I can do this better, please!
@Sam; I tried that, maybe in the wrong places, but it didn't work

Comment: Nice, I have added it as an official answer. If you think it's okay, please validate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.widgets-modal form').submit( function(){...` is incremental. It appends the same function at every click. So if you click three times, the `.submit` function will be attached and executed three times. Try adding `.unbind()` before `.submit`, to clear all previous functions attached.

Comment: I would like to add I used .off(), instead of .unbind(), because it is deprecated

Comment: Is it really? I don't see anywhere in the doc that unbind() is deprecated.  https://api.jquery.com/unbind/  .off() is used to clear one special event from an element , like .off('click'), but unbind() removes everything.

Comment: I thought I read that somewhere, but like you said, it isn't in the docs. I will change it to unbind then!